# mysql error 1064 with statement ALTER COLUMN

Tags: mysql, sql

Following statement gives me an error:

```
ALTER TABLE employee ALTER COLUMN Startdate datetime
```

Error:

> Mysql error 1064

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype`

Answer (score 1):

Mysql does not use ALTER COLUMN.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try the following

```
ALTER TABLE `DbName`.`table_name` 
CHANGE COLUMN `column_name` `new_col_name` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
`Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables] OR mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databa` at line 1